# MongoDB query with 300k documents takes more than 30 seconds

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, fastify

Ok, as said in title, I have "performance issue" where I need to get all documents from a collection but it takes too long. Players collection contains around 300k documents with small size and query in service goes like this:

```
async getAllPlayers() {
  const players = await this.playersCollection.find({}, {projection: { playerId: 1, name: 1, surname: 1, shirtNumber: 1, position: 1 }}).toArray();

  return players;
}
```

Overall size is 6.4MB. I'm using Fastify adapter, fastify-compress and mongodb native driver. If I remove projection, it takes almost a minute.

Any idea how to improve this?

Comment: try to not to fetch all the data at once, use limit and skip and read data in chunks from mongodb

Comment: Have you tried tuning the batch size?

Comment: Could you paginate your endpoint?

Comment: Thanks all, eventually will limit to 10k and load more on scroll. 10k takes 980ms so it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The best time I get is 8 seconds, where `fast-json-stringify` give me more than 10 seconds boost over 300k records:

[image: boost]

```
'use strict'
// run fresh mongo
// docker run --name temp --rm -p 27017:27017 mongo

const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
const fjs = require('fast-json-stringify')

const toString = fjs({
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    playerId: { type: 'integer' },
    name: { type: 'string' },
    surname: { type: 'string' },
    shirtNumber: { type: 'integer' },
  }
})

fastify.register(require('fastify-mongodb'), {
  forceClose: true,
  url: 'mongodb://localhost/mydb'
})


fastify.get('/', (request, reply) => {
  const dataStream = fastify.mongo.db.collection('foo')
    .find({}, {
      limit: 300000,
      projection: { playerId: 1, name: 1, surname: 1, shirtNumber: 1, position: 1 }
    })
    .stream({
      transform(doc) {
        return toString(doc) + '\n'
      }
    })

  reply.type('application/jsonl')
  reply.send(dataStream)
})

fastify.get('/insert', async (request, reply) => {
  const collection = fastify.mongo.db.collection('foo')

  const batch = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

  for (let i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    const player = {
      playerId: i,
      name: `Name ${i}`,
      surname: `surname ${i}`,
      shirtNumber: i
    }
    batch.insert(player);
  }

  const { result } = await batch.execute()
  return result
})

fastify.listen(8080)
```

In any case, you should consider to:

- paginate your output
- or pushing the data into a bucket (like S3) and return to the client a URL to download the file directly, this will speed up a lot the process and will save your node.js process from this data streaming

Note that the compression in node.js is a heavy process, so it slows it down a lot the response. An nginx proxy adds it by default without the need to implement it in your business logic server.

Comment: Wow! Will  definitely try!